# DateTime representation and conversion shows the wrong date

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a new date from parameters that I receive from a request.

I have this code:

```
DateTime datefrom = DateTime.ParseExact(DateFromTextBox1.Text,"dd/mm/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToUniversalTime();

int hoursFrom = HourFromTextBox1.Text!=String.Empty?Convert.ToInt32(HourFromTextBox1.Text):0;

int minutesFrom = HourFromTextBox1.Text != String.Empty ? Convert.ToInt32(MinuteFromTextBox1.Text) : 0;

date1 = new DateTime(datefrom.Year, datefrom.Month, datefrom.Day, hoursFrom, minutesFrom, 0).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

I get something like this:

```
2018-01-19 13:11:00
```

When the initial date that I tried to parse was this:

```
"20/10/2018"
```

The hours and minutes are correct. But the day and month are not.

I think the output is because the time on my computer is something like this:
11-Oct-18. This may be a cultural problem.

How can I get the correct date from what is expected?

Comment: In your first line you are using `dd/mm/yyyy`. You need `dd/MM/yyyy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting time to Universal Time making the result differ. Try `"dd/MM/yyyy"` as parse string. `"mm"` is used for minutes in datetime parsing refer this documentation for datetime custom formats [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Ex -

```
DateTime datefrom = DateTime.ParseExact("20/10/2018","dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(datefrom);   //20.10.2018 00:00:00  without universal time

DateTime datefromUniversal = DateTime.ParseExact("20/10/2018","dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToUniversalTime();
Console.WriteLine(datefromUniversal);   //19.10.2018 22:00:00  with universal time
int hoursFrom = "13"!=String.Empty?Convert.ToInt32("13"):0;

int minutesFrom = "11" != String.Empty ? Convert.ToInt32("11") : 0;

var date1 = new DateTime(datefrom.Year, datefrom.Month, datefrom.Day, hoursFrom, minutesFrom, 0).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Console.WriteLine(date1);
```

Hope now you understood